# Rename [azuresphere] to [azure-sphere]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

For Azure Sphere service, currently the [azuresphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuresphere) tag is used in Stack Overflow. To make best practice for tag alignment across all channels including Q&A and Stack Overflow and also meet the Microsoft standards to keep all tags under same umbrella with the **azure-** prefix, my suggestion is to rename the [azuresphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuresphere) tag to **azure-sphere**.

For example in SO Azure IoT Hub uses [azure-iot-hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-iot-hub) and Azure IoT Edge uses [azure-iot-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-iot-edge) tags.

Microsoft Q&A follows the same standards as the following above link for Azure Sphere : [azure-sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sphere)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-sphere.html

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401301/rename-azureblockchainservice-to-azure-blockchain-service