# Rename [azureblockchainservice] to [azure-blockchain-service]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

For Azure Blockchain service, currently [azureblockchainservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azureblockchainservice) tag is used in Stack Overflow. To make best practice for tag alignment across all channels including Q&A and Stack Overflow and also meet the Microsoft standards to keep all tags under same umbrella with the **azure-** prefix, my suggestion is to rename the [azureblockchainservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azureblockchainservice) tag to **azure-blockchain-service**.

For example in Stack Overflow:
Azure IoT Hub uses [azure-iot-hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-iot-hub), Azure IoT Edge uses [azure-iot-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-iot-edge)and Azure BlockChain Workbench uses [azure-blockchain-workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blockchain-workbench)

Microsoft Q&A follows the same standards as mentioned above.

Link for reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-blockchain-service.html

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401287/rename-azuresphere-to-azure-sphere?cb=1